# Unable to execute SonarScanner analysis due to Time out Exception

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner, sonarscanner

Versions :
Sonar : 8.8.0.42792
Sonar-scanner : 4.5.0.2216
MacOS : Catalina 10.15.6

**sonar-project.properties :**

```
sonar.projectName=camel
sonar.projectKey=camel-key
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources=src
sonar.language=java
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.java.binaries=build/classes
```

**sonar-scanner :**

```
  #----- Default SonarQube server
  sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 # tried with local IP 127.0.0.1 & network IP too
  
  #----- Default source code encoding
  sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

Sonar Qube is UP, status is running , can access console too.

I have ZScaler security firewall, protected with password so can't modify or stop it.

Now, while executing below command from Project root directory where sonar-project.properties file exists , I am getting following error.

> `Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out`

Any particular reason and how to solve this , please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, the port `9000` is **blocked** by Zscaler (*My machine has Zscaler turned on, I've not made any changes to Zscaler settings*). However the solution I found is to change the Sonarqube's port to something else, eg `9090`

#### Steps

1. Go to `sonarqube-8.7.0.41497/conf` (Im using 8.7, so you need to go the version you're using)
2. Open up `sonar.properties`
3. Change `sonar.web.port=9000` to `sonar.web.port=9090`
4. Launch your sonarqube again by running `sonar.sh start`
5. Try scanning your project, by running `sonar-scanner` where your `sonar-project.properties` is.

Comment: Yes, I solved this that way only, zscaler does use 9000

Comment: I also faced this issue. As I was using sonarscanner for gradle, updated the host url in global gradle properties as mentioned in https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/9.8/analyzing-source-code/scanners/sonarscanner-for-gradle/